# Makefile for loop - variables never get set

Tags: makefile

I have got below for loop to iterate over predefined list and to set variables which are used further in the make

```
for ENTRY in $(ARRAY); do \
    if test "$${ENTRY}" = $(PRE_ID); then \
        echo "$${ENTRY}"; \
        PRE=1; \
        NON_PRE=0; \
        echo "$(PRE)"; \
        else echo "$(PRE_ID)"; \
        NON_PRE=1; echo "$(NON_PRE)"; \
    fi \
done
```

In the above loop all the conditions checking executed properly but the variables set statements are not executed. the echos on $(PRE) and $(NON_PRE) always prints empty like "". 
Any clue or hint to solve this issue would be helpful.

Comment: How are you defining `$(ARRAY)`?  Can you give an example of how you are setting it?

Comment: its like this ARRAY=one two three. I don't have problem in iterating over the entries in the ARRAY. One of the either of if/else after the for loop gets executed but the variables PRE or NON_PRE doesn't get set with the values that assign here. Its always has empty ""

Comment: Please show the context in which the `for` loop is used -- a complete example if possible.

Comment: for eample the make has target "all" which has the 2 recipes "check" and "install" as below. The check recipe has the above mentioned for loop an the install will use the variables PRE and NON_PRE to decide on some install steps.

all: check install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused between instructions for `make` itself and the commands executed by `make`.

What you've shown here is not (by itself) valid Makefile syntax, but a shell script. The only thing `make` does with it is expand `make` variables (the `$(...)` / `$$` parts), giving

```sh
for ENTRY in one two three; do \
    if test "${ENTRY}" = whatever-PRE_ID-is; then \
        echo "${ENTRY}"; \
        PRE=1; \
        NON_PRE=0; \
        echo ""; \
        else echo "whatever-PRE_ID-is"; \
        NON_PRE=1; echo ""; \
    fi \
done
```

(here I'm assuming `PRE_ID` is defined elsewhere in the Makefile, but `PRE` / `NON_PRE` are not, so they turn into ... nothing). This resulting command is then passed to `sh -c` and executed as a shell script.

The shell will set `PRE` and `NON_PRE` as shell variables, but your command makes no use of them, and they will be gone once the loop has finished executing (because shell variables don't persist past the death of the shell).

To fix this code, you'd have to explain more about what you're trying to achieve, because currently this is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Due to the staging nature of `make` (the Makefile is parsed and `make` variables are processed first, then shell commands are run as part of rule processing), you simply cannot set `make` variables from a shell loop.

Comment: Agree, I couldn't really figure out a Makefile syntax to iterate over defined list to set the variables PRE, NON_PRE which I use later in Makefile. This for loop is shell script. I'm not getting a way to have global make variables, I even tried initializing PRE, NON_PRE to '0' in the beginning of the Makefile, but after this for loop run it still has the initialized values as you pointed its shell script and vanishes upon shell exit. I need help in setting the variables in the for loop (iteration is must) and which I can use in the later part of Makefile. Any input on that how can i do that?

Comment: Any further help on this? how to set makefile variables inside shell for loop and make it available through out the makefile life?